# Apache Camel Exchange to Propagate from one process to another

Tags: apache-camel

I am looking out for a way by which in Apache Camel, I can stop a exchange to propagate from one process to another, without stoping and restarting the route itself. I had below route configured and what I am basically looking out is to return the exchange from messageMultiplierProcessor based on some conditions without changing/modifying the exchange body or setting/resetting it headers.

```
<route id="business-logic-route">
<from uri="direct:business-logic-endpoint"/>            
<setProperty propertyName="esq.route.name">
    <constant>TestRoute</constant>
</setProperty>
<process ref="messageMultiplierProcessor" />
<process ref="calculatedFieldsProcessor" />
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for. Perhaps you could add some pseudo code to your route to clarify what you want to happen?

Comment: @Paul : As stated in the question itself, based on some business scenario I need to continue the exchange flow to other process in the route, so I am looking out for some configurable property in apache camel route by which the flowing exchange in a route can be skipped propagating to other processes....hope this clears the question, also I really don't understand why this -1 ?

Comment: Simply don't understand why some people out here are so hurry in downvoting, instead of posting there doubts if question is unclear or comment out there understanding about the question posted

Comment: Do you just mean you want to conditionally end your route after the first processor? If that's the case just use <when>...</when> & <stop/>

Comment: @Paul - Thanks for your help, this was exactly what i was looking for, also can you post this as an answer so that I can accept the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally stop a route at any point using "when" & "stop":

`<when>some condition</when>
<stop/>`